# Using mysql USE with C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to find some relevant documentation in how to open a connection using the MySQL .NET Connector and then switch databases using the USE command.

The MySQL documentation says, well, nothing. That works for console but how do I actually use this in C# code?

Comment: Are you encountering a specific exception when attempting this?

Comment: Well not yet, I simply have no clue how to implement it, could use a sample or similar :)

Answer (score 2):

To connect to a MySQL server in C# you use a connectionstring to define the server, the database, the user and the password.
If you want to use multiple databases, you should create a connectionstring for each database.
Look on this site for examples of connectionstrings: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql.